# gRPC keepalive ping fail after the second time

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-c++

I've tested grpc keepalive using official c++ helloworld sample.
However keepalive ping fail after the second time.

Client says `Keepalive watchdog fired. Closing transport.`

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc

I've modified client and server code as follows:

```cpp
  // client main()

  // ....

  // keepalive configuration
  grpc::ChannelArguments args;
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS, 1);
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 10000);
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 3000);
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA, 0);

  GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateCustomChannel(
      target_str, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(), args));
  std::string user("world");

  // send rpc request at 1 minute interval
  while (true) {
    std::string reply = greeter.SayHello(user);
    std::cout << "Greeter received: " << reply << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60 * 1000));
  }
```

```cpp
  // server main()

  // ....

  // keepalive configuration
  builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS, 1);
  builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA, 0);
  builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MIN_RECV_PING_INTERVAL_WITHOUT_DATA_MS, 10000);

  // ....
```

After build, run in terminal:

```sh
$ export GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
$ export GRPC_TRACE=http_keepalive,connectivity_state,http
$ ./greeter_server
$ ./greeter_client # in other terminal
```

client output:

```
...
I0115 17:09:27.910828000 123145533800448 chttp2_transport.cc:2821]     ipv6:[::1]:50051: Start keepalive ping
I0115 17:09:27.912454000 123145534337024 chttp2_transport.cc:2845]     ipv6:[::1]:50051: Finish keepalive ping
I0115 17:09:37.916751000 123145533800448 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffc2c010200 CLIENT [ipv6:[::1]:50051] state IDLE -> WRITING [KEEPALIVE_PING]
I0115 17:09:37.916792000 123145533800448 writing.cc:129]               CLIENT: Ping sent [ipv6:[::1]:50051]: 0/0
I0115 17:09:37.916800000 123145533800448 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffc2c010200 CLIENT [ipv6:[::1]:50051] state WRITING -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
I0115 17:09:37.916844000 123145533800448 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffc2c010200 CLIENT [ipv6:[::1]:50051] state WRITING -> IDLE [finish writing]
I0115 17:09:37.916851000 123145533800448 chttp2_transport.cc:2821]     ipv6:[::1]:50051: Start keepalive ping
I0115 17:09:40.921260000 123145534337024 chttp2_transport.cc:2883]     ipv6:[::1]:50051: Keepalive watchdog fired. Closing transport.
I0115 17:09:40.921305000 123145534337024 chttp2_transport.cc:2912]     transport 0x7ffc2c010200 set connectivity_state=4
I0115 17:09:40.921316000 123145534337024 connectivity_state.cc:159]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_transport[0x7ffc2c0104a0]: READY -> SHUTDOWN (close_transport, OK)
I0115 17:09:40.921325000 123145534337024 connectivity_state.cc:167]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_transport[0x7ffc2c0104a0]: notifying watcher 0x7ffc2b606490: READY -> SHUTDOWN
I0115 17:09:40.921521000 123145534337024 connectivity_state.cc:79]     watcher 0x7ffc2b606490: delivering async notification for SHUTDOWN (OK)
I0115 17:09:40.921595000 123145534337024 connectivity_state.cc:159]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x7ffc2b607958]: READY -> IDLE (helper, OK)
```

server output:

```
...
I0115 17:09:27.910972000 123145419530240 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state IDLE -> WRITING [PING_RESPONSE]
I0115 17:09:27.911006000 123145419530240 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state WRITING -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
I0115 17:09:27.911030000 123145419530240 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state WRITING -> IDLE [finish writing]
I0115 17:09:37.916957000 123145420066816 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state IDLE -> WRITING [PING_RESPONSE]
I0115 17:09:37.916989000 123145420066816 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state WRITING -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
I0115 17:09:37.917010000 123145420066816 chttp2_transport.cc:806]      W:0x7ffb1a809000 SERVER [ipv6:[::1]:52295] state WRITING -> IDLE [finish writing]
I0115 17:09:40.921613000 123145419530240 chttp2_transport.cc:2912]     transport 0x7ffb1a809000 set connectivity_state=4
I0115 17:09:40.921664000 123145419530240 connectivity_state.cc:159]    ConnectivityStateTracker server_transport[0x7ffb1a8092a0]: READY -> SHUTDOWN (close_transport, OK)
I0115 17:09:40.921674000 123145419530240 connectivity_state.cc:167]    ConnectivityStateTracker server_transport[0x7ffb1a8092a0]: notifying watcher 0x7ffb19905040: READY -> SHUTDOWN
I0115 17:09:40.921743000 123145419530240 connectivity_state.cc:79]     watcher 0x7ffb19905040: delivering async notification for SHUTDOWN (OK)
I0115 17:09:40.921758000 123145419530240 chttp2_transport.cc:1837]     perform_transport_op[t=0x7ffb1a809000]:  SET_ACCEPT_STREAM:(nil)((nil),...)
```

environment:

```
grpc 1.42.0
macOS(intel) 11.6
```

gRPC C++ keepalive document:

https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_keepalive.html

Comment: This looks like an I/O polling problem. In the current I/O polling model that gRPC uses, to perform I/O (reading and writing on sockets and noticing when new data has arrived) threads are basically borrowed from the application. So if you only make RPCs once per minute, then you'll basically only perform I/O once per minute

Comment: ^ more on that, there is a backup I/O poller which basically runs every GRPC_CLIENT_CHANNEL_BACKUP_POLL_INTERVAL_MS milliseconds and then quickly polls open client side sockets to see if any new data has arrived that needs to be acted on. By default, GRPC_CLIENT_CHANNEL_BACKUP_POLL_INTERVAL_MS is 5000 i.e. 5 seconds

Comment: ^ more on that, because the timeout is 3 seconds, probably the backup poller doesn't have a chance to get to it. I suspect that if you either set GRPC_CLIENT_CHANNEL_BACKUP_POLL_INTERVAL_MS=1000 or increase your timeout to beyond 3 seconds

Comment: Note that this polling problem is a somewhat fundamental problem associated with the gRPC synchronous APIs. https://github.com/grpc/proposal/pull/245/files is an open proposal to fix this problem long term. In the meantime, another quick solution is to simply make RPCs more frequently

Comment: I set GRPC_CLIENT_CHANNEL_BACKUP_POLL_INTERVAL_MS and it worked!
Is there any way to set GRPC_CLIENT_CHANNEL_BACKUP_POLL_INTERVAL_MS programmatically, instead of using an environment variable? @apolcyn